# save values of hopCount and dstSeqNo in file

Tags: c, ns-3

I use ns3 and I want to save the values of

```
 m_hopCount,m_dstSeqNo(aodv-packet.cc)
```

in file my problem is when i use this code it save just the first line and doesn't save the others values if any one has any suggestion please tell me and thank you.

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("/home/ns3/ns-allinone-3.19/ns-3.19/src/aodv/model/cc.txt" , "w+");

fprintf(fp," %d %d \n",m_hopCount,m_dstSeqNo);
fclose(fp);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Images of text are not searchable, nor are they accessible. Please [edit] the question to include the code as text, formatting it appropriately with either the format as code button or by indenting it with four spaces. Also is this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55995464/gethopcount-and-store-them-in-file your earlier question?

Comment: Change "w+" to "a".  "w+" creates a new file discarding existing content, while "a" appends data to an existing file, creating the file if it does not yet exist.

Comment: thank's sir it work